# how do I detect if user logged in using my login button or login from facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I implemented my Facebook login to my website, but how do I know if the user used my login button OR the user logged in by going to Facebook.com?
I want to detect and take some action if he or she did not use my Facebook login button.  I'm using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a parameter to the links you're using for login buttons. For example

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?login=facebook
http://www.example.com/index.php?login=custom
```